# Fit ul to the size of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following markup (well this is a rough estimate, but it will do). 
http://jsfiddle.net/6UxRU/1/

```
<fieldset>
<div class="parent">
    <input id="inpt" type="text" />
    <ul class="checkboxgroup">
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" />Dominican Republic</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" />Equatorial Guinea</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" />Egypt</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" />French Southern Territories</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Is there any way i can make the `ul` width fit the width of the input(even when the input's width changes)? Also, is there a better way of forcing the two elements to always be in the position they are now besides making the parent width 200px?

Comment: When does the `input` width change?

Comment: It won't necessarily change, but it is a possibility that someone will come and set for example `width:100%`. Also I see someone suggested a possible answer to this question at the beginning, might be just me but I don't see what they meant by that

Comment: How? By changing the CSS?

Comment: yes, by changing the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/6UxRU/4/ 
The code can be improved but trying to find out if this is the end result you want.

```
<fieldset>
<div class="parent">
    <input id="inpt" type="text"/>
    <ul class="checkboxgroup">
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" />Dominican Republic</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" />Equatorial Guinea</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" />Egypt</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" />French Southern Territories</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</fieldset>

.checkboxgroup {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    background: yellow;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 5px;
    clear: both;
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
li {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: x-small;
    display: table-row;
}
.checkboxgroup label {
    float: left;
    word-break: normal;
    /*margin-left: 10px;*/
}

.parent{
    background-color: green;
    overflow:hidden;
    display :inline-block;
}

#inpt{
    display:block;
    width:100%;        
}
```

Comment: The `inline-block` for parent answered my second question, so thanks :). But if you change the width of the input here, the `ul` will stay the same.

Comment: Now why would you want to do that?When do you expect the width of the input change?

Comment: Well i'm trying to turn this into a jQuery plugin which converts a normal select element to a checklist. And the changing of the input width is just a case i thought would be relevant if someone tries to use the plugin and they don't want the input width to be 100%. However it might indeed not be a relevant concern. The jQuery part of this "plugin" i'm comfortable with, but the css part is killing me :)